# Conect Java client with Python server

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcpclient

I made a server python with the next code (i think the rest of the code isn't necessary):

```
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data+'\r\n')

conn.close()
```

and when i try to received the echo with a Java client, i get a strange message when printing on console:

```
Mensaje recibido = java.io.DataInputStream@1cf2a0ef
```

At server point, I'm receiving good the message: Hola Mundo.

The code in Java is:

```
    DataInputStream ims;
    String data;

    s = new Socket(HOST,PORT);

    oms = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ims = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    oms.writeUTF(ms);
    ims.read();
    data = ims.toString();

    oms.close();
    ims.close();
    s.close();

    return data;
```

I think that ims.toString() is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to assign data to a string read from the stream:

```
data=ims.readUTF();
```

the toString() method in the stream just returns a representation of the object id, it's meaningless.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF()

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `ims.toString` is wrong. If python is sending a UTF-8 string you could use `ims.readUTF()`.

Comment: I thought that readUTF() don't return the string, i didn't read the documentation of Java, thank you!

Comment: It's working, i don't need more help at the moment hahaha thanks!