# Socket Android client

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I did a TCP client on Java and works fine, but when I import the class to my Android project, it doesn't work.

Android code:

```
// ...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SEND);
    ssid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSsid);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPass);
    debugText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.debugText);

    cliente = new ClienteTCP();
    debugText.setText("Version 1-prealpha");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something in response to button click
            demo(v);
        }
    });
}

public void demo(View view) {

    cliente.configure(ssid.getText(), pass.getText());

    CharSequence cs = cliente.sendMessage("Hola Mundo");

    if ( cs != null)
        debugText.setText(cs);
    else
        debugText.setText("ERROR OCURRED");
}
// ...
```

I always get the "ERROR OCURRED" message, I try to use another IPs, but all of them works fine on Java and not on android.

The class code:

```
private CharSequence SSID, pass;
private String HOST = "52.28.45.92"; // My external server i tried with localhot server too ...
// of course i have a server aplication running hahaha
private int PORT = 5000;

private Socket s;
private DataOutputStream oms;

// ...
public CharSequence sendMessage(String ms) {
    DataInputStream ims;
    CharSequence data = null;

    try {
        s = new Socket(HOST,PORT);

        oms = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ims = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        oms.writeUTF(ms+getFull());
        data = ims.readUTF();

        oms.close();
        ims.close();
        s.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

I think it can be due to my emulator, any ideas? is the code wrong?

EDIT: Server code:

```
# ...
# Wrote on Python:
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data+'\r\n')

conn.close()
```

Comment: Two things: 1. You should run `public void demo(View view)` on different thread than Main. 2 Can you post log error?

Comment: There is no error, just cs is always null

Comment: The `DataInputStream` `readUTF()` method is not the same as `readLine()`, here are more [details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()) the data that your Python program sends can't be read using the `readUTF()` method.

Comment: And why it's read on my Java project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829036/conect-java-client-with-python-server what's the diference?

Comment: You return data==null and then you say you have ERROR_OCCURRED. But you will have had a catch: `catch (IOException e)`. So you are already printing the stack trace but you could also log e.getMessage() to see the reason of the exception. Or return e.getMessage() there to see it directly.

Comment: Ok, I try again and say to you! thx for the help

Comment: And place that code in an AsyncTask or thread as said before. You will have a `NetworkOnMaiThreadException` now. See the logcat.

Comment: instead `e.printStackTrace()` use `android.util.Log.d("log", e.getMessage())` to print the error and post it

Comment: 04-23 22:21:09.099    2227-2227/com.example.urbanclouds.hitek D/log﹕ socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied) ups... seems to be permissions :/ don't kill me please, later i fix threads theme

Comment: @JoseteManu I guess in this case it works because the Python program is sending the data that it had received, data which was send using the `writeUTF(...)` method and because of that, it has correct format ( except the `\r\n` which will probably be added to the next package).

Comment: PERFECT! With permission it's working fine!! Now, threads, i'll try to fix them